# MDX replace null - get dimension ranges

Tags: null, mdx

Hi I have the following MDX query:

```
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[count_X]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY {[DIM_DAYS].Children} ON 1 
from [Cube]
```

With the following result set:

```
Axis #0:
{[DIM_S].[A], [DIM_LOCALIT].[X], [DIM_ANNO].[2013]}
Axis #1:
{[Measures].[count_X]}
Axis #2:
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[#null]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[0]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[1]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[2]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[3]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[4]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[5]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[6]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[7]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[8]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[9]}
{[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[10]}
Row #0: 468
Row #1: 69
Row #2: 70
Row #3: 53
Row #4: 90
Row #5: 77
Row #6: 78
Row #7: 119
Row #8: 159
Row #9: 155
```

I'd like to: 
1) change the #null label with NOT SPECIFIED
2) make ranges for the days as [1 - 30] [31 - 60]

Could someone help me? THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with Member [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[NOT SPECIFIED] AS
            [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[#null]                       // just rename it
     Member [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[1-30] AS
            Aggregate( [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[1] : [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[30] )
     Member [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[31-60] AS
            Aggregate( [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[31] : [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[60] )
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[count_X]} ON 0,
       NON EMPTY {
           [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[NOT SPECIFIED],
           [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[1-30],
           [DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[31-60]
       } ON 1 
  from [Cube]
```

should deliver what you stated in your question. However, I am not sure why you leave out `[DIM_TEMPO_RILASCIO].[0]`.  And I am not suer about dimension and hierarchy names in detail, but maybe you can transfer my solution to your real situation.